# Draw shapes and fill with color in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, graphics, drawing

I am drawing an image in a canvas with typescript/javascript.
The coordinates that i get are from lines and arcs, i read this data from a database (the order of the lines and arc's are random). 
The drawing of the picture goes ok, but i need to fill the drawn shape with a color. doing this with moveTo and lineTo and then calling fill does not work. for one because of the random order of the lines and arcs. and two because of the fact that an arc can be inward aswell so it colours the outside of the 'room'.

Example picture:

[image]
Snippet of my drawing code:

```
    let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas-view");
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '500');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '500');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (ctx != null)
    {
        for (let count = 0; count < image.lines.length; count++)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(image.lines[count].startPoint.x, image.lines[count].startPoint.y);
            ctx.lineTo(image.lines[count].endPoint.x, image.lines[count].endPoint.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        for (let count = 0; count < image.arcs.length; count++)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(image.arcs[count].center.x, image.arcs[count].center.y, image.arcs[count].radius, this.DegreesToRadians(image.arcs[count].startAngle), this.DegreesToRadians(image.arcs[count].endAngle));
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
```

is there a way to Color the inside of this shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sorting random lines and arcs

How to create a continuous paths from a random list of line and arc segments, with each line and arc in a random direction.

#### Step 1 Arc end points

To fill the shape you need to wait until you have all the lines and arcs. Then you have to order them so that they make one continuous outline.

For that you will need the start and end points, which you have for the lines but not as coordinates for the arcs, so you need to calculate them.

This function adds the start and end points to an arc.

```
function arcEnds(arc){
    const d2r = d => d * Math.PI / 180; // deg to rad
    arc.startPoint = {
       x : Math.cos(d2r(arc.startAngle)) * arc.radius + arc.center.x,
       y : Math.sin(d2r(arc.startAngle)) * arc.radius + arc.center.y
    }
    arc.endPoint = {
       x : Math.cos(d2r(arc.endAngle)) * arc.radius + arc.center.x,
       y : Math.sin(d2r(arc.endAngle)) * arc.radius + arc.center.y
    }
    return arc;
}
```

#### Step 2 Create a single array

To optimise the construction of the line you need to create a single array that holds both the lines and arcs. As you do that you can also calculate the arc end points.

```
function createSegmentArray(lines, arcs) {
     return [...lines, ...arcs.map(arcEnds)]; // add lines and end point calculated arcs
}
```

#### Step 3 Create function to match points

As you can expect some floating point error in the end point calculations you will need to have a tolerance, so that you can determine if 2 points are equal.

The are two ways to see if two points are at the same location. I will use the square of the distance as it is a little neater.

```
// 1 pixel tolerance
const isSame = (p1,p2) => (((p1.x - p2.x) ** 2) + ((p1.y - p2.y) ** 2)) < 1;
```

#### Step 4 Create unsorted and sorted arrays

So now you create the array pf segments

```
 const segs = createSegmentArray(image.lines, image.arcs);
```

Create a second array to hold the ordered segments.

```
 const orderedSegs = [];
```

#### Step 5 Sort by matching end or start points

Then start at the first segment, remove it from the segs array and find the segment that has a matching end or start (we don't know the direction yet). If a matching end point is not found then the shape is not closed and can not be filled so throw an error to indicate this. You will have to add a catch handler. Or you may prefer to break from the loop and just flag an error

You will also need to reverse a segment that is in the wrong direction. For a line you just swap the end points, for the circle you need to swap the end points, and the end angles, and add a flag to indicate the direction has reversed.

```
 var current = segs.shift();
 while(seg.length > 0){
     let reverse; // if true the segment needs to be reversed
     const index = segs.findIndex(seg => { // find segment with matching end or start
         if(isSame(current.endPoint, seg.startPoint)){
            reverse = false;
            return true
         }
         if(isSame(current.endPoint, seg.endPoint)){
            reverse = true;
            return true
         }
         return false;
      })
      if(index === -1){ throw new Error("The shape is not closed and can not be filled") }
      orderedSegs.push(current);
      current = segs.splice(index,1)[0]; // get the connected seg
      if(reverse){
           if(current.center){ // is a circle
                const t = current.endPoint;
                current.endPoint = current.startPoint;
                current.startPoint = t;
                const t1 = current.endAngle;
                current.endAngle= current.startAngle;
                current.startAngle = t1;
                current.reversed = true;
           }else{
                const t = current.endPoint;
                current.endPoint = current.startPoint;
                current.startPoint = t;
           }
      }
      // loop until no more segments
  }
  // push the last seg onto the array
  orderedSegs.push(current);
```

#### Step 6 Render the results.

Now you have all the points in the order that they are connected you can render them in that order but you have to reverse the direction of arcs

```
  const d2r = d => d * Math.PI / 180; // deg to rad
  var i;
  ctx.beginPath();
 // arcs have start points now so dont have to check type for first point
  ctx.moveTo(orderedSegs[0].startPoint.x, orderedSegs[0].startPoint.y);
  for(i = 0; i < orderedSegs.length; i++){
       var seg = orderedSegs[i];
       if(seg.center){ // is a arc
           ctx.arc(
               seg.center.x, seg.center.y, seg.radius,
               d2r(seg.startAngle), d2r(seg.endAngle), seg.reverse
           );
       }else{
           ctx.lineTo(seg.endPoint.x, seg.endPoint.y);
       }
  }
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
```

And that is the process.

#### Warnings

1. This will not work if you have holes in the shape. For each segment there must be a segment that has a matching end or start point.
2. It will work if there is not segment between the first and last. It assumes that there is a line segment between them and will not indicate that the path is not closed. You will need to test the start point of the first segment in  `orderedSegs` array is the same  `isSame` as the end point of the last segment in `orderedSegs` array
3. This will not work if  there are points where more than two segments join. If this is so the path created will move along the first connected segment which may not be the correct segment. It will not complete the sort and will throw an error even though it may have found the correct closed path.
4. This ignores the arc direction and assumes that the arcs are unified in direction (either all CW or all CCW). If they are not so then you will have to make appropriate corrections while rendering the path.
5. Start and end points of the arc created above may not be the same as the end points you have for the line. They are just objects with an x, y. If you wish them to be the same type of object you will need to do that in the `arcEnds` function.
6. As I don't have a data set I can not test the above code, it is therefore very likely that there are any number of typos. The code is intended as a guide as to the logic of the process only. You should use it to create your own version and not just copy and paste as it likely will throw errors due to the typos.